# Find all the null records for all fields in a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3

I figured out that I can use field calculator on a single column in ArcGIS 10.3 attribute window as follows:

```
def RemoveNULL(x):
    if x is None:
        return ''
    elif x == '':
        return '0'
    else: return x

RemoveNULL(str(!myxField!))
```

What I really want to do is find a way to find all the null records for all fields in a shapefile that are NULL (truly empty or '') and change them to zero but preserve all other values (double or int numeric). I don't care about text.

Comment: Shapefiles, based as they are on dBase-III+, don't support the concept of numeric nulls. 
Please **edit** the question to include the GIS software in use.

Comment: I concur with Vince, if you see NULL in a field it's a string of 4 characters and not DBNull.Value/None/NULL (depending on programming/scripting language).

Comment: arcGIS desktop 10.3 built in python field calculator, thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

I really like using feature layers and selection for this kind of thing. Below I find all my relevant fields, then try selecting `Nulls/''`. If there's a selection, I field calculate.

I haven't tested the script, so it may not be perfect.

```
def removeNumericNulls (inFeatureClass):
    import arcpy

    #Relevant field types
    fieldTypes = ["Double",
                  "Single",
                  "Integer",
                  "SmallInteger"]

    #Get fields
    fields = []
    for fieldType in fieldTypes:
        fields += [f.name for f in
                   arcpy.ListFields (inFeatureClass, field_type = fieldType)]
    #Feature layer to allow selection
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inFeatureClass, "lyr")

    for field in fields:
        #SQL to select nulls
        fieldDelim = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters ("lyr", field)
        sql = "{} IS NULL OR {} = ''".format (fieldDelim)

        #Select nulls
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "", sql)

        #Skip if no selection/no null values
        if not arcpy.Describe ("lyr").FIDSet:
            continue

        #Calc field
        arcpy.CalculateField_management ("lyr", field, "0")

    arcpy.Delete_management ("lyr")
```

Comment: are you running this from python.exe and calling the .mxd or  are you running this inside arcgis through python?

Comment: You can copy/paste this into the Python window in ArcGIS, add the layer to the table of contents you wish to scrub, and then in the Python window: `removeNumericNulls ({lyr})` where `{lyr}` is the name of the layer in your table of contents. Or you can find IDLE (Start -> All Programs -> ArcGIS -> Python 2.7 -> IDLE (Python GUI)). In the python shell paste the function. Then you can use the full path of any feature class or table for the function's input. Such as: `removeNumericNulls (r"C:\temp\temp.gdb\example")`. The full path is easiest to copy from ArcCatalog. Don't forget the `r`.

Comment: Still the fact remains that NULL is not part of the DBASE(IV) spec see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28411/how-to-have-a-nullable-field-included-in-a-shapefile-using-the-geotools-library (answer by whuber) and especially http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005600000013000000 in *When should I not use a shapefile?* there shouldn't be any NULL values in the table to select... it would be different if it were a geodatabase feature class.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson sometimes you gotta go with the spirit of the question, not the letter of the question. I suspect poster uses the term shapefile for other spatial data types. I hear it used by my fellow GIS professions improperly all the time.

Comment: That's new to me, though it doesn't sound inconceivable that the terms *shapefile* and *feature class* become interchangeable thereby referring to a *feature class* as *a shapefile*... stranger things have happened by pseudo-GIS users (those that need to understand about 1% of GIS to perform their tasks but are trying hard to say the right things).