# How to get around "The field is not nullable" error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, angles

I have a shapefile of lines.
I want the angle of every line calculated in a field.

I am using the script below in arcmap, but when it encounters a line that is horizontal, it stops calculating any remaining values and gives the following error:

> **The field is not nullable.**

I searched for answers to similar questions, not getting too far with them.

Where I originally found this code:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/20473#21719

Pre-logic Script code:

```
import math  
def GetAzimuthPolyline(shape):  
 radian = math.atan((shape.lastpoint.x - shape.firstpoint.x)/(shape.lastpoint.y - shape.firstpoint.y))  
 degrees = radian * 180 / math.pi  
 return degrees
```

Expression:

```
GetAzimuthPolyline( !Shape!)
```

Comment: Is there any blank record(row) in the featureclass/shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a divide by zero error I would try changing:

```
import math  
def GetAzimuthPolyline(shape):  
 radian = math.atan((shape.lastpoint.x - shape.firstpoint.x)/(shape.lastpoint.y - shape.firstpoint.y))  
 degrees = radian * 180 / math.pi  
 return degrees
```

to:

```
import math  
def GetAzimuthPolyline(shape):  
  if shape.lastpoint.y - shape.firstpoint.y != 0:
    radian = math.atan((shape.lastpoint.x - shape.firstpoint.x)/(shape.lastpoint.y - shape.firstpoint.y))  
    degrees = radian * 180 / math.pi  
    return degrees
  else:
    return 90
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no "null" field with shapefile because it uses dbf table. see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28411/how-to-have-a-nullable-field-included-in-a-shapefile-using-the-geotools-library)

Apart from that, you could adapt your code for horizontal lines

```
import math  
    def GetOrientation(shape): 
     if  (shape.lastpoint.y == shape.firstpoint.y):
       degree = 90
     else:  
       radian = math.atan((shape.lastpoint.x - shape.firstpoint.x)/(shape.lastpoint.y - shape.firstpoint.y))  
       degrees = radian * 180 / math.pi  
     return degrees
```

Answer (score 0):

This will calculate classic type direction, i.e. counterclockwise from East =positive.

```
import math
def getAngle(shp):
 p1=shp.firstPoint;p2=shp.lastPoint
 dX=p2.X-p1.X;dY=p2.Y-p1.Y
 try:
  z=math.atan(-dY/dX)
 except:
  z=math.pi/2 
  if dY>0: z=-math.pi/2
 z=z*180/math.pi
 if dX<0:z+=180
 z=-((z+180)%360-180)
 return z
```

To call it use:

```
getAngle( !Shape! )
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

As it is frequently the case, the idea borrowed from one of the old posts of @whuber, I struggle to locate it though.